# How to call a method which assigns a new value to argument if it's null in Java?

Tags: java

I'm thinking about `validateEntity`. What do you think about it?

```
T validateEntity(@Nullable T entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
    {
        entity = DEFAULT_ENTITY;
    }
    return entity;
}
```

Comment: 1. Tell more about idea, wchich API is planned to use. 2. modifying data during validation seems egsotic

Comment: you can use `Optional` e.g `Optional.of("s").orElse("g")`

Comment: @JacekCz Entity is a field of another object so yeah, probably we should just return "DEFAULT_ENTITY" without modifying the object itself.

Comment: New `Optional` is one of good solutions to `if( x==null)` hell (depends how question can be understood)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a validation, it's replacement. I think the method name is incorrect.

```
// replaceIfNull as possible option
T getDefaultIfNull(@Nullable T entity) {
    if (entity == null) 
        return DEFAULT_ENTITY;

    return entity;
}
```

Using thernary operator:

```
T getDefaultIfNull(@Nullable T entity) {
    return entity == null ? DEFAULT_ENTITY : entity;
}
```

Java 8:

```
T getDefaultIfNull(@Nullable T entity) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(entity).orElse(DEFAULT_ENTITY);
}
```

With Guava liblary `com.google.common.base.Optional<T>`:

```
T getDefaultIfNull(@Nullable T entity) {
    return Optional.fromNullable(entity).or(DEFAULT_ENTITY);
}
```

Guava `com.google.common.base.MoreObjects`:

```
T getDefaultIfNull(@Nullable T entity) {
    return MoreObjects.firstNonNull(entity, DEFAULT_ENTITY)
}
```

Actually, as you can see there is the Java 8 tools and external libraries that can establish reasonable doubt on existance of such method.

If you decide yo go without any libraries or using Java version lower than 8, you can stick to the first approach.

Comment: hard to wait positive effects of `Optional` with 'old' thinking. Whole context should be rethinked in new way and porbably method will be eliminated

Comment: @Jacek Cz, probably. But if the author of the question asked about options, he probably was not aware aboit it or uses some older version of Java. It's just a way to start.

Comment: With Guava: [`return MoreObjects.firstNonNull(entity, DEFAULT_ENTITY);`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#firstNonNull(T,%20T)) (assuming the default entity is non null; I guess it would have to be for this method even to make sense).

Comment: @Andy Turner, good point. Added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

If you want to validate some element, the method should probably return a boolean or a value representing some validation status *about* the entity, rather than an entity itself.

Otherwise, if you want to replace the element — you cannot actually "replace" an object itself with another object. For instance, the following method returns the given entity if it is not `null`, or `DEFAULT_ENTITY` if it is.

```
T guaranteeNotNull(@Nullable T entity) {
    return (entity != null ? entity : DEFAULT_ENTITY);
}
```

But it depends on the caller if the returned value is actually assigned to a variable, replacing another value. The following snippet has actually no effect:

```
String someValue = null;
guaranteeNotNull(someValue);
System.out.println(someValue); // Still null
```

The best thing is actually to either shortcut the method to this:

```
T guaranteeNotNull(@Nullable T entity) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(entity).orElse(DEFAULT_ENTITY);
}
```

or get rid of the method altogether.